# Manfred Schroeder Virial Theorem Derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, virial-theorem

I'm working on a project about fractals in physics and I picked up Manfred Schroeder's fascinating book: Fractals, Chaos and Power Laws.
In one of the early parts (titled Similarity in Physics: Some astounding consequences), he states the mathematical definition of a homogeneous function in the context of explaining similarity on differing length scales.

$$V(\lambda \vec{r}_1, \lambda \vec{r}_2, \ldots, \lambda \vec{r}_N) = \lambda^n V(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2,\ldots, \vec{r}_N)$$

He goes on to say that taking potential energy as a homogeneous function of degree $k$ (of the spatial coordinates) and kinetic energy as a homogeneous quadratic function (of velocity) you can "almost immediately" derive that:

$$2⟨T⟩=k⟨V⟩$$

using the definition of a homogenous function.
But I can't work out what this immediate step is.

I looked at a classical derivation of the [Virial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) and I don't see how I'd get the $k$ in front without at some point taking a derivative with respect to $\lambda$. Nor do I see any reason to take a derivative with respect to $\lambda$. Any ideas?

Comment: First equation in your post is a mathemathical equation which is supposed to hold for all $\lambda$. I don't understand what is your problem with taking derivative with respect to $\lambda$?

Comment: I'm just unsure as to how taking a derivative with respect to $\lambda$ fits into the derivation. I suppose my question should be what use is the derivative of Potential or KE with respect to $\lambda$ in the derivation?